# Obscuring a username with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that serves up various information for users who have accounts on it by accessing information listed under a username and a category. Using the variable names, `u` and `c`, the url looks like this:

```
www.originalwebsite.com/user.php?u=username&c=43
```

I want a user-defined custom domain to remove any evidence of a username variable or variable name. Other variables (like category) are fine to remain. Ideally, this would result in the following link pointing to the one included before:

```
www.customdomain.com/c=43
```

My reasons being that the custom domain would be unique for the user and, therefore, would be remove the need to specify the user (in theory, not in practice so far) as well as presenting the site from a custom domain in a manner that looks like a single site, rather than the portal like options of the original.

I can get `www.customdomain.com/u=username&c=43` to work but am trying to think of the best method to remove reference to the username when using the custom domain (both the variable identifier and the variable itself). I'm struggling to think of how I'll inform the original website of what user account to use if it's not mentioned in the url itself.

At the moment my best idea is to let `user.php` handle this with a condition of whether the request is from *originalwebsite.com* or a custom domain. If finds that it's the latter, it checks it against a database listing and finds the relevant user settings discreetly. This feels like quite a slow procedure, however.

If my example is not clear, think of sites like Tumblr, where you can add a custom domain and, from that point on, urls make no reference of your user name.

Comment: Don't pass c=43 in your url, just use /user/43, so nobody see the parameter name

Comment: Ah, I think I've been misinterpreted. I'll edit the original to word it clearer but I want to remove any reference to there being a username, so I need the username not to be the url either, as well as the parameter.

Comment: Well, your example without username and parameter would look like `www.customdomain.com/` – but that will not lead anywhere but to the homepage. Can you post a sample URL? How should that look like? What if you want to open a user page when coming from a search engine or typing it in directly? (hint: do not rely on the referrer)

Comment: Apache alone cannot decode an id 43 into a corresponding username. You need to have a script in there to perform the lookup for you.

Comment: @feeela, it's only the username variables I want to keep obscured. URL of original and ideal rewrite are included above. I've no worries about search engine results - using the same example of Tumblr as in my question, there are many custom domains for Tumblr where there is still a Tumblr subdomain for if you Google hard enough. The php file will handle the difference of receiving a username variable if it's coming from the original sites domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some discussion here and further research, it seems as though there's no quickfire way of doing this. It looks like I'm stuck with either keeping some form of reference that can identify a username in the url, using a cookie or sticking with my original idea of referencing the custom domain against a database to find the appropriate user and settings.

I've gone with the database referencing option as I need to remove references to any username from the url and I can't always rely on cookies. I need a 100% success rate of correct redirection.

I've changed my `user.php` file to check if the request has come from `originaldomain.com` or `newdomain.com`. If it's from `originaldomain.com`, it looks for a username variable in the url as it should have one for any user that doesn't have a custom domain. If it comes from a different domain, it checks to see if this domain is listed in the database and finds the user from this. There's a few catches that I'll need to trial but I've got 90% of the issue solved.